# Как в regexp шаблоне исключить его же часть из результата

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vbscript

Регулярка:

```
\[A-za-z]{2,}.1cws\
```

Текст,который я хочу "поймать", выделен жирным:
http://SomeAdress/SomeAdress/ws/**Testws**.1cws?wsdl

http://regexr.com/3f2db

Comment: На каком языке нужно, чтобы работало?

Comment: VisualBasicScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью опережающей и ретроспективной проверки можно добиться, чего вы хотите:

```
/(?<=\/)([A-za-z]{2,})(?=.1cws)/
```

`(?<=\/)` - проверяет, встречается ли перед указанным выражением символ `/`.
`(?=.1cws)` - проверяет, встречается ли после указанного выражения набор символов `.1cws`.

Посмотреть пример работы: https://regex101.com/r/0Nv9gh/1.
Это будет работать в языках с поддержкой PCRE. В JS нет ретроспективной проверки.

Выражения внутри опережающей и ретроспективной проверки не захватываются в результирующий набор. Подробнее об этих проверках можно почитать в статье "[Опережающие и ретроспективные проверки в регулярных выражениях](https://habrahabr.ru/post/159483/)".

---

Поскольку JS не поддерживает ретроспективные проверки, можно захватывать интересующие символы в отдельную группу и работать уже с ней:

```
/\/([A-za-z]{2,}).1cws/
```

Посмотреть пример работы: https://regex101.com/r/josgHv/1.

Comment: @СергейSer, вы преувеличиваете. Практические задачи, ответы здесь на вопросы, необходимость в работе. Прочитайте вот эту пару статей: http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/regexp_1 и http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/regexp_2. Они помогут вам разобраться с регулярками. Если вам помог мой ответ, проголосуйте за него и отметьте верным.

Comment: Увы, реализация видимо не поддерживает это. (PCRE).
При таком патерне RegExp не проходит test

Answer (score 0):

Для решения моего вопроса нужно добавить **"positive look-ahead"** конструкцию в конец шаблона.

Замечание: **look-behind** выражения не поддерживаются в некоторых реализациях, например в javascript

```
[A-za-z]{2,})(?=.1cws)
```